# Sitecore Gecko.js showModalDialog error

Tags: google-chrome, sitecore, sitecore7

I encountered an error this morning after upgrading to the latest version of chrome, 37 (although that may be a coincidence).

The error is: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function, scBrowser.showModalDialog" on line 345 of the Gecko.js file in "/sitecore/shell/controls/" folder.

```
showModalDialog(url, arguments, features);
```

This occurs when attempting any function that opens a popup,  i.e. right click the Desktop and select "properties".

Anyone encountered this, and is there a fix?

Thanks very much.

UPDATE - Found this post which may be helpful to anyone wanting to re-enable this: http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/08/sitecore-modal-pop-ups-are-not-working.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it the latest version of Chrome has removed the showModalDialog function :/

http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html

Im sure a fix for this is on the way but if its affecting customers maybe this setting will help ?

http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realised the it was deprecated. A bit of a pain, but most of our clients will be using IE anyway, so I doubt it will be much of any issue for them, and we'll just recommend they use IE if they encounter the problem.

Comment: The registry settings worked on my local system. Trying them as domain policy soon.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore has released patches for this issue for versions 6.4 - 7.0.

You can find the patches in their support KB article here -> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527